# Как на Slider Revolution сделать так чтобы при разных размерах девайсов фон все равно был по центру?

Tags: css, wordpress

Всем привет!
Мне нужно сделать так чтобы фон слайдера был всегда посередине
У меня тут возникла проблема со Slider Revolution на [Сайте](https://yukkident.ru/) Wordpress
Если поподробнее то:
Изображения на фоне слайдера, на главной странице сайта жестко хромает на мобилах и падах, это немного и смешно, и не очень, как сделать так чтобы фон в Slider Revolution был всегда по середине?
Надеюсь на помощь

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Читайте документацию на слайдер. вы можете для мобильных устройств менять фоны, тексты, анимации, делать адаптив, в том числе менять позиционирование. Есть видео и туториалы от разработчиков этого слайдера на официальном сайте.